# TextInput type password in react native paper

Tags: typescript, react-native-paper

I have a question, currently I have this code for my password type input and I have the functionality to see or not see the password, and the problem is that when I write the password and change the state to see it it works fine and I can continue writing and when I return it and I change it and I want to continue writing, as soon as I type the character it erases what it had, how can I solve that?

```
 <TextInput
            label='Contraseña'
            mode='flat'
            style={{
              marginBottom: 17,
              backgroundColor: '#304d4a',
              borderTopRightRadius: 10,
              borderTopLeftRadius: 10,
              fontWeight: 'bold',
            }}
            selectionColor='white'
            underlineColor={'#958f8f'}
            activeUnderlineColor={'#fff'}
            textColor='white'
            secureTextEntry={showPassword}
            textContentType='password'
            value={password}
            autoCorrect={false}
            onChangeText={(text) => {
              console.log(text)
              setPassword(text)
            }}
            onFocus={() => {
              setShowIcon(true)
            }}
            onBlur={() => {
              setShowIcon(false)
            }}
            right={
              showIcon && (
                <TextInput.Icon
                  icon={showPassword ? 'eye-off' : 'eye'}
                  color='white'
                  forceTextInputFocus={false}
                  onPress={() => {
                    setShowPassword(!showPassword)
                  }}
                />
              )
            }
          />
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
onChangeText={(text) => {
               console.log(text)
               setPassword(text)
             In the }}
```

section, you can try writing the setPassword() part before console.log(). I think there may be an error caused by the use of setPassword. I recommend you try again by changing the priority of something.